# How to use Validation Rule on Button Click Command

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm

I have a TextBox  with OneWay Mode, so validation does not happen automatically.

```
<TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="SelectedValue.Customername"
                         ElementName="customerListBox" 
                         Mode="OneWay"
                         >
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <validators:NameValidator ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
```

I have a button :

```
<Button Content="Save"  Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
```

Now on ViewModel , I want to validate the Text Input before doing anything else:

```
SaveCommand = new RelayCommand(
                param=>
                {
                   //If validation is true 
                  //Then Execute Res

                }

                );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ditch the UI validation rules and have your VM implement [IDataErrorInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) and [INotifyDataErrorInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo(v=vs.110).aspx).

Think about it--your save command should not execute unless the data in your VM is valid.  That means the validation logic should be in your VM, and not in your UI.

Implementing these interfaces makes it trivial to check whether or not you execute/can execute and fire appropriate events when CanExecute has changed.